# How to apply correct regex?

Tags: regex

I have a special task which requires lots of `regex` and `javascript` `parsing`.

My head is almost exploding, so maybe I'm tired and forgot some small thing else I'm not newbie to regex so perhaps someone will point me to good direction here and show me where I did mistake.

So I have this regex code:

> ((?<=\ffmpg=).+(?=////u0026cs=nt))

to get the value of substring between 2 strings. The first string is called: 
 `ffmpg=` from this string it should start and it will end just before the other string start called `//u0026cs=nt`

The problem is that it is working fine until the html page contains only one parameter with the same name; because the source html has inside like 10's of ffmg and the same end string called cs=nt.
I can not even make regex to count the characters because every time you visit the html page the number of characters are different, sometimes +3 else +10. So the only way is to get this sting from the start of param1 to the end of param2.

This is the string I need to get: `1714248%2C23851735%2C23804281%2C23839597%2C23357901%2C3313341%2C3316343%2C23848795%2C3300132%2C26853996%2C3300114%2C3315790%2C23857451%2C23856472%2C23851936%2C3300161%2C3314786%2C23856652%2C23859863%2C23837993%2C23833479%2C23861502%2C23842630%2C23842986%2C23861012`

This is the source html example:

> \u0026doc=IcuU5Oy8\u0026pen=V9PXaHoOp1gKD25rgAg\u0026ffmpg=1714248%2C23851735%2C23804281%2C23839597%2C23357901%2C3313341%2C3316343%2C23848795%2C3300132%2C26853996%2C3300114%2C3315790%2C23857451%2C23856472%2C23851936%2C3300161%2C3314786%2C23856652%2C23859863%2C23837993%2C23833479%2C23861502%2C23842630%2C23842986%2C23861012\u0026cs=nt\u0026token=gHgig8eLY3qsQ0bXa\\u0026doc=IcuU5Oy8\u0026pen=V9PXaHoOp1gKD25rgAg\u0026ffmpg=1714248%2C23851735%2C23804281%2C23839597%2C23357901%2C3313341%2C3316343%2C23848795%2C3300132%2C26853996%2C3300114%2C3315790%2C23857451%2C23856472%2C23851936%2C3300161%2C3314786%2C23856652%2C23859863%2C23837993%2C23833479%2C23861502%2C23842630%2C23842986%2C23861012\u0026cs=nt\u0026token=gHgig8eLY3qsQ0bXa\\u0026doc=IcuU5Oy8\u0026pen=V9PXaHoOp1gKD25rgAg\u0026ffmpg=1714248%2C23851735%2C23804281%2C23839597%2C23357901%2C3313341%2C3316343%2C23848795%2C3300132%2C26853996%2C3300114%2C3315790%2C23857451%2C23856472%2C23851936%2C3300161%2C3314786%2C23856652%2C23859863%2C23837993%2C23833479%2C23861502%2C23842630%2C23842986%2C23861012\u0026cs=nt\u0026token=gHgig8eLY3qsQ0bXa\

I have copied 3 times the same just for this purpose because it is very big html source and I doubt I can upload it here.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your questions, you use `(?<=\ffmpg=)` where `\f` will match a form feed character which is not present in the data example. If you meant to use `\\f` it will match `\f` which is also not present in the example data.

You could get the match using a capturing group instead of using lookarounds as lookbehinds are not widely supported by all browsers.

If you just want to get a single match, you can omit the `/g` global flag.

If you use `.+` you will match too much as the .+ will match until the end of the string and then backtracks until the first time it can match `\\u0026cs=nt`

What you could do instead is be specific in what you would allow to match which for the current string is a character class with the following characters `[AC0-9%]+`

You could broaden the character class with a range to match chars `A-Z` instead of `AC` for example and add more chars or ranges as required.

```
ffmpg=([AC0-9%]+)\\\\u0026cs=nt
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UhbDHd/1)

For example

```js
const regex = /ffmpg=([AC0-9%]+)\\\\u0026cs=nt/;
const str = `\\\\u0026doc=IcuU5Oy8\\\\u0026pen=V9PXaHoOp1gKD25rgAg\\\\u0026ffmpg=1714248%2C23851735%2C23804281%2C23839597%2C23357901%2C3313341%2C3316343%2C23848795%2C3300132%2C26853996%2C3300114%2C3315790%2C23857451%2C23856472%2C23851936%2C3300161%2C3314786%2C23856652%2C23859863%2C23837993%2C23833479%2C23861502%2C23842630%2C23842986%2C23861012\\\\u0026cs=nt\\\\u0026token=gHgig8eLY3qsQ0bXa\\\\\\\\u0026doc=IcuU5Oy8\\\\u0026pen=V9PXaHoOp1gKD25rgAg\\\\u0026ffmpg=1714248%2C23851735%2C23804281%2C23839597%2C23357901%2C3313341%2C3316343%2C23848795%2C3300132%2C26853996%2C3300114%2C3315790%2C23857451%2C23856472%2C23851936%2C3300161%2C3314786%2C23856652%2C23859863%2C23837993%2C23833479%2C23861502%2C23842630%2C23842986%2C23861012\\\\u0026cs=nt\\\\u0026token=gHgig8eLY3qsQ0bXa\\\\\\\\u0026doc=IcuU5Oy8\\\\u0026pen=V9PXaHoOp1gKD25rgAg\\\\u0026ffmpg=1714248%2C23851735%2C23804281%2C23839597%2C23357901%2C3313341%2C3316343%2C23848795%2C3300132%2C26853996%2C3300114%2C3315790%2C23857451%2C23856472%2C23851936%2C3300161%2C3314786%2C23856652%2C23859863%2C23837993%2C23833479%2C23861502%2C23842630%2C23842986%2C23861012\\\\u0026cs=nt\\\\u0026token=gHgig8eLY3qsQ0bXa\\\\`;

console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);
```

Comment: the code is ok but i mention earlier that the html source have more then one same character and with this code I get like 5 same results, I need only 1 string thats all I asked to "tell the regex that only one string and if page have more same strings just forget about them'

Comment: @JanaPaluchova Did you try this exact code? there is not `/g` flag used so you should get only a single match. I have updated the regex101 link which had the `/g` flag still enabled.

Comment: I have 'gm" but the code is correct only i need only one string and IF html page contains more same ffmpg it give me more resuts thats the problem not the /g OR /gm

Comment: @JanaPaluchova I am not sure if I get what you mean. The global flag will match all occurrences so if you omit that, you will have a single match. You don't need the `/m` multiline flag as there are no achors `^` and `$` used. The `.+` will match any character except a newline. So if you have multiple occurrences like this https://regex101.com/r/iHGyjz/1 you will overmatch it. If you match all chars you will match all until the last occurrence https://regex101.com/r/IRIreB/1. You could also use lookarounds to get a match without the group https://regex101.com/r/oc5iZH/1

Comment: ok thank you it helps me but still in c# code I'm getting multiply results in response :'( never mind I will figure out until Monday I hope

Comment: @JanaPaluchova This is a C# demo where you would get a single match https://ideone.com/pqWPAJ

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=ffmpg=)([A-F0-9%]+)
```

**Explanation**

Since your string only consists of url-encoded characters, you can use `[A-F0-9%]+`character class to capture it. It will stop when next string starts because there will be a backslash.

See online demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/853jXe/2/).

Comment: ok thx but I need only one string your regex example shows all 3, so I mention that the html contains similar names but i need only one time so how do I do that?

Comment: can we say to Regex that parse only one string and if similar name do not do that next?

Comment: @Jana Paluchova you can just take first match from the matches array

Comment: ok all your examples works I just found where I did mistake :) instead of groups(1) I simple added .value and not substring and my code works :D thanks to all for your time anyways have a good weekend!